# Python calculating average waiting time in queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, queue

Suppose I have a queue, with each element representing a customer waiting for their order to be fulfilled. How would I implement the python time module to increment the waiting time if more customers pile up an decrease the waiting time if customers have been served.

```
import time
class Queue:
    #Constructor creates a list
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = list()
        self.start_time = 0
        self.start_time2 = 0

    #Adding elements to queue
    def enqueue(self,data):
      #Checking to avoid duplicate entry (not mandatory)
        if data not in self.queue:
            self.queue.insert(0,data)
            if self.start_time != 0:
                self.start_time2 = time.time()
                self.start_time += self.start_time2

            self.start_time = time.time()
            return True
        return False


    #Removing the last element from the queue
    def dequeue(self):
        if len(self.queue)>0:
            #calculate time between ordering and serving: 
            elapsed_time = time.time() - self.start_time
            print('Order took', elapsed_time)
            #decrease current waiting time
            self.start_time = self.start_time - elapsed_time
            print('Current waiting time is', self.start_time)
            return self.queue.pop()
        return ("Queue Empty!")

    #Getting the size of the queue
    def size(self):
        return len(self.queue)

    #printing the elements of the queue
    def printQueue(self):
        return self.queue

    def time(self):
        start_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time))

customerQueue = Queue()
customerQueue.enqueue('Test1')
customerQueue.enqueue('Test2')
customerQueue.enqueue('Test3')
print(customerQueue.queue)
customerQueue.dequeue()
print(customerQueue.queue)
```

Comment: in your `enqueue` and `dequeue` functions you're returning from the function before the timing code has a chance to run. Did you notice that?

Comment: You should consider writing a class for queue items and give them attributes `start_time` and `end_time`. A start time for the queue itself doesn't make much sense in this context. For the queue you need to keep track of the average time needed to process one queue item. Either you store a list of times or you store the running average by storing the number of already processed items. When you enqueue or dequeue, you can then approximate the waiting time with the length of the queue.

Comment: @SimonFink, could I not include start_time and end_time as attributes in my queue class? Or use inheritance or a similar concept. Could you link an example solution? Regards

Comment: No, you need to keep track of every item in the queue, so it makes no sense to store it in the `Queue` class. Alternatively, you can store a list, with the time it took for each item. This one can live in the `Queue` class.

Comment: @Simon Fink. Ok thanks. How would I calculate the average queue waiting time. As in, would I find the average from the group of queue times of each customer order of the day or an average for every customer served across weeks/months etc?

Comment: It depends on the use case and what seems the most appropriate.

Comment: The use case being an information system for a manager of a restaurant/shop to look at to see how long waiting times on average are @Simon Fink